# Irreagular shape of div

Tags: css, css-shapes

I would like to create an div element with irreagular shape:

[image: DEMO]

Is it possible to create two divs - first should contain HEAD TITLE and irreagular shape (look at screen) and second which should contain text?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can create all the divs you want. but no, divs cannot have irregular shapes. they're ALWAYS rectangular. you can have weird borders/margins on them, but a div is fundamentally always rectangular.

Comment: you sure you searched and you found nothing about `border-radius`?

Comment: You'll have to learn how to fake this stuff. Everything is possible, even if it only _looks_ like it. That, and what @Mr.Alien said. Actually, just remember that.

Comment: I know what is a border-radius but I still don't know how I can create this div. Can u give me an example ?

Comment: The web is plenty of examples, look for div with irregulars shapes for example :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a height of the title div so that you get a complete circlular border. That way, your 'title' will have a nice round feel to it, rather than a 'square offish' feel to it:

```css
.title {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 90px;
  text-align: center;
  background: lightgray;
  margin-bottom: -70px;
}
.text {
  border: 2px solid black;
  min-height: 100px;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="title">Some Title</div>
<div class="text">Some Text. Ok, I mean quite a bit of text, but just enough to span more than a single line...Some Text. Ok, I mean quite a bit of text, but just enough to span more than a single line... But apparently, do to that, I needed to duplicate this line of text.
  But now after explaining that I needed to expand on the text, it's got longer! Long enough to definately span more than a single line!</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is what you looking for, using what Mr Alien said:

```css
 .wierd{
            border:2px solid #000;
            border-radius:50% 50% 0 0;
            border-bottom:0;
            color:#F00;
            width:400px;
            text-align:center;
        }

        .rect{
            border:2px solid #000;
            width:600px;
        }
```

```html
   <div class="wierd">HEAD TOP TITLE</div>
<div class="rect">
    text text text text text text text text
</div>
```

Comment: Just play with border radius % or pixels etc. to make it exactly how you want it.